# How to properly level / build a fence for in my back yard?

Tags: fence, level, backyard, project-planning

I'm building a fence in my backyard it's about 300ft of fence and this is my first time doing a project like this.

I wasn't 100% sure the best method for leveling, my yard is mostly flat no big slopes but there is some grades to it like with any yard as no yard is perfectly flat. Each side of the fence will run about 100ft.

I started off running the back braces perfectly level to the ground using a 4ft level and making sure they were perfect on installing each one but I soon noticed as I'm moving further down the line that there is a decent size grade and my bottom post as I move further down is around 8 inches higher off the ground then when I started.

[image]

[image]

[image]

In the second picture you can see how I'm building the front panels which I leveled the top border of that panel too which is sloping up and If I continue this router by the end of the fence line going level I'll be 8 inches or so off the ground which I don't want.

So my question is what is the best way I should be doing this? My yard I thought looked pretty level but it appears it's not nearly as I thought.

Do I get the idea of level completely out of my mind and for the braces just measure up from the ground and keep them all the same and have the panels flow with the movement of the ground?

Any help would be great appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

#### Level Each Section

With a gradual slope - i.e., no more than a couple of inches per section - I would make each section level but with some offset an inch or two as needed so that each section is approximately the same distance from the ground.

Comment: Pro tip: If you're married, draw some diagrams of the choices you're okay with, then let your spouse make the final choice.

Comment: @mrog Absolutely - you wouldn't want to do something of-fence-ive.

Comment: Right, because that could create a barrier of sorts.

Comment: @manassehkatz Doing this would make the top of the panels offset though right? I really would like to have the top of the fence all flow together so am I better off just not making it level and going the same height off the ground for each brace support?

Comment: @Greenhoe - Correct, but I see that routinely on slopes. The alternatives are either a gradually widening gap on the bottom - which, IMHO, looks even worse, or trim the panels so that the ones installed at the highest level are shorter and they all have the same top and they all hug the ground. But that is a LOT more work. The other option is to use a scalloped (rounded with lowest point in middle) or rounded (highest point in middle) top so that even though the panels will be slightly different heights it won't be as noticeable.

Comment: @manassehkatz What if I just don't worry about the level at all and it's all height base so each rail is the same height off the ground then on the front I can make it flow with the ground to so it should match the slope but with everything moving together.

Comment: The problem is that each panel would be titled to match the slope. But if you do that then as the slope changes you will have overlaps or gaps at the left/right edges. If each panel is level then you don't have the problem.